# Помогите с php preg_match_all и переменной из sql

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Помогите пожалуйста, столкнулся с проблемой в **php**.

**preg_match_all** не работает когда беру патерн из **MYSQL**.

Собственно вот патерн: **`(?<=<div\ class="single-content">)[\w\W]*?(?=</div>)`**

Если так то все гуд:
**`preg_match('/(?<=<div\ class="single-content">)[\w\W]*?(?=</div>)/', $content_page, $body);`**

Но если я его тащу из sql:
**`preg_match("/$regex_body/", $content_page, $body);`**

**Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'd'**

Помогите! как решать эту проблему, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: ограничители другие поставьте с краев выражения, какой нить `~regex~` (которых заведомо не будет в том, что вы подставляете), или экранируйте `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так не работает:

```
preg_match('/(?<=<div\ class="single-content">)[\w\W]*?(?=</div>)/', $content_page, $body);
```

Надо `\/div` без пробелов между слэшами:

```
$regex_body = '/(?<=<div\ class="single-content">)[\w\W]*?(?=<\/div>)/';
```

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос